# Asp.Net binding

Tags: asp.net

Can I somehow evaluate a binding expression like this in codebehind?

```
" Click('<%#SaveButton.ClientID%>'); DoSomethingElse('<%#CancelButton.ClientID%>')"
```

Comment: what is the exact use case? of course you can call SaveButton.ClientID in code behind

Comment: I was hoping that you could use eval to evaluate a string with binding expressions like above for some dynamic stuff.

Comment: as @Fernando is suggesting, = should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You should replace '#' by '='.

Answer (score 0):

Supposed you used button, you can do sth like that in codebehind:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "functionName();");
```

^^

Answer (score 0):

If it's necessary to bind the script on the page. There is some not very elegant way:

```
<%# String.Format("Click(\"{0}\";DoSomethingElse(\"{1}\")",SaveButton.ClientID,CancelButton.ClientID) %>
```